# C# - How create an arch shape using for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

This is the first reverse pyramid

like

```
for ( i= 10; i >= 1; --i)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
            {
                Console.Write(j+i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

For the second one, I want the pyramid reversed, but this time it needs to be a mirror image of the first one, and I also want it to start at the same line where the first one ended, I want it to look like an arch.

can anyone help me

output i want something like [this](https://unsplash.com/s/photos/arch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var output =
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => 10 - x)
        let ns = Enumerable.Range(1, i).Select(x => x + i)
        select $"{String.Concat(ns).PadRight(20)}{String.Concat(ns.Reverse()).PadLeft(20)}");

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

I get this output:

```
1112131415161718192020191817161514131211
101112131415161718    181716151413121110
910111213141516          161514131211109
891011121314                141312111098
789101112                      121110987
678910                            109876
5678                                8765
456                                  654
34                                    43
2                                      2
```

Comment: thanks, but if posible i want the output using for loop

Comment: @Player91 - That's a little harder. This way was easy for me.

Comment: okay no issues i will try this one, thanks a lot